# What's the proper syntax in Rebol to execute an in-memory block of code including the header

Tags: rebol

This syntax doesn't work:

```
>> do load/header {rebol [Title: "Hello World"] Print System/Header/Script/Title }
** Script Error: Invalid path value: Header
** Near: Print System/Header/Script/Title
```

I want to get the meta-data in header.

My goal is mostly to be able to execute a whole rebol source including header to the clipboard and execute it in console by doing something like do read clipboard:// that doesn't work if I include the header, I can't strip it since I need it.

Answer (score 3):

Rewritten in response to comment.

Use **load/header/next** to create a two-item block: the script header followed by the script content:

```
loaded: load/header/next {rebol [Title: "Hello World"] Print "this is my script"^/a: 99 + 5 print a}
probe loaded/1   ;; shows the header
do loaded/2      ;; executes the script
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain the goal: My goal is to be able to execute a whole rebol source including header to the clipboard and execute it in console by doing something like do read clipboard:// that doesn't work if I include the header, I can't strip it since I need it.

Comment: rewritten to address your clarification